# How to expose/bubble events to outside in Composite Winforms Controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, custom-controls

I have a `CompositeControl` with 3 buttons, and I don't want to have these buttons as public members from my `CompositeControl`. But I also want to expose their Click event individually so the user of this control can subscribe to them.

I am not sure how to do this without duplicating the same events in my control and raising each button's Click event separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how to do this without duplicating the same events in my control and raising each button's Click event separately.

This is really the proper way to handle this.  You will want to duplicate the event, but give it a new, proper name.

Typically, this means exposing the "click event" with a name that's related to the activity of the button, not the button itself.  For example, if you had a refresh button, I'd expose the event as something like:

```
public event EventHandler RefreshRequested;
```

Then, internally, you'd listen to the button's click event and raise the refresh requested event.  This also provides you the flexibility, later, to change the internal representation (if you wanted to use something other than a button, for example).

Comment: Thanks Reed. I am not sure how to connect the master event of the composite control with the internal events. When the user subscribes to my event, then I will sub the same event to the internal ones?

Comment: @JoanVenge The simplest way is to just always subscribe to the internal events (ie: in your constructor), and bubble them up to your main event.  Standard event handling for raising the event will prevent unhandled subscribers from causing any problems...